# Where can I keep frequently changed contact info in my Asp.Net Core project so I can update it (like a config file)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Ye Olde Asp.Net projects used to have a `web.config` file where I could (with no small difficulty) create a custom config section and a "config reader" class and keep a list of contacts:

```
<myConfigSection>
  <contacts>
    <contact name="Luke SkyWalker" email="luke@degobah.com" phone="123-456-7890" />
    <contact name="Anakin SkyWalker" email="whiner@deathstar.com" phone="987-654-3211" />
  </contacts>  
</myConfigSection>
```

This let me access it pretty easily from my code, and if I needed to update the contacts, I could just update the `web.config`.

I notice that the `web.config` is missing in the new hotness that is Asp.Net Core.  What's the preferred method of implementing something like this?

Comment: The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) provides example for that, [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#json-configuration-provider) specifically is about json files.

Comment: @colinD The linked examples refer to configuration data, not "content"-data. Arguably the OP's example is (ab)using `web.config` to store website content and not settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, a database file - you could use a simple sqlite database if you like.

Otherwise, a JSON file would work great for this. You can also still use XML if you use `System.Linq.Xml` (which has a much nicer and modern API compared to `System.Xml`) - just replace my use of `JsonConvert` with some XML deserialization library or your own XML reading code.

1. Create a `.json` file with the details in:

   ```
   {
       "contacts": [
           {
               "name": "Luke Skywalker",
               "email" : "luke@degobah.com",
           },
           {
               "name": "Anakin SkyWalker",
               "email" : "whiner@deathstar.com",
           },
           // etc
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Create C# POCO types that model the data in the file:

   ```
   class ContactsFile {
       public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
   }
   class Contact {
       public String Name { get; set; }
       public String Email { get; set; }
       public String Phone { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Read it somewhere in your app:

I assume the data will be edited regularly, so you should reload it every time you use it - in which case you should create a new injectable service class for it, like so. Note that you do not need an interface (but it's useful for testing).

```
    public interface IContactsStore
    {
        Task<ContactsFile> ReadAsync();
    }

    public class DefaultContactsStore : IContactsStore
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;

        public DefaultContactsStore(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            this.env = env;
        }

        public async Task<ContactsFile> ReadAsync()
        {
            String path = Path.Combine( this.env.ContentRootPath, "Contacts.json" );

            String fileContents;
            using( StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader( path ) )
            {
                fileContents = await rdr.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactsFile>( fileContents );
        }
    }


    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IContactsStore contactsStore; 

        public MyController( IContactsStore contactsStore )
        {
            this.contactsStore = contactsStore;
        }

        [Route("/contacts")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ListContacts()
        {
            ContactsFile cf = await this.contactsStore.ReadAsync();

            return this.View( model: cf );
        }
    }

    // In Startup.cs:
    public void ConfigureService( ... )
    {
        // etc
        services.AddSingleton<IContactsStore,DefaultContactsStore>();
        // etc
    }
```